# developing ios 4.1 and deploying to ios 4.1 and above

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

I'm developed application with ios 4.1 sdk and I want to deploy to ios 4.1 OS and above OS iPhone and iPad.Is it possible?

Comment: Some might even say it's advisable until you can be certain that the majority of your userbase have installed iOS5. It'll solve a lot of these problems though, as it makes updates a push-button affair.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, until the methods you have used are deprecated and removed in future OS.

Please have a look at the following link.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/cross_development/Using/using.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002000-SW6

Comment: how to check which methods is deprecated in newer iOS version?

Comment: You can find them in the API document.